# IComparable<T> for interface

Tags: c#, comparison

I use PowerCollections `OrderedBag<IObject>` to get difference between two multisets, so I need `IComparable<IObject>` in every IObject. Problem - `IObject` is just marker. Different classes have not natural order. How to make comparsion in such case? I tried

```
public virtual int CompareTo(IObject o)
{
    return this.Equals(o) ? 0 : -1;
}
```

but that gives wrong number in OrderedBag.Difference() here:

```
copiesInThis = this.NumberOfCopies(item);
```

**Solution?**

Add "order", such as `Measure` < `Comment` < `Word`. Add `IComparable<>` for each IObject. And than compare all possible cases:

```
var measure = o as Measure;
if (measure != null)
    return 1;

var comment = o as Comment;
if (comment != null)
    return this.CompareTo(comment);

var word = o as Word;
if (word != null)
    return -1;

throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
```

Comment: Somewhat strange you are trying to order items that have no order... You can return comparison of hash codes to keep a<b and b>a consistent (`this.Equals(o) ? 0 : this.GetHashCode() < o.GetHashCode() ? 1 : -1;`)

Comment: `CompareTo` is used for sorting, `Equals` is used for equality. Can you describe more clearly what the exact problem is? "Wrong number in OrderedBag.Difference()" is not really helpful. Nowhere in your sample code do you refer to CompareTo. What code are we missing here?

Comment: And usually it is `Equals` that calls `Compare`, not the other way around. For example: `public static bool Equals(Type obj1, Type obj2) { return Type.Compare(obj1, obj2) == 0; }`

Comment: `GetHashCode()` may return `Id.GetHashCode()` and different entities may have same Id, so this does not work.